# Is there any significant difference between using GenerationType.IDENTITY and using GenerationType.SEQUENCE and providing allocationSize=1

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I use hibernate and PostgreSQL.My question is If we create a sequence like `...start 1 increment 1`, will it be efficient than using the IDENTITY strategy? And if so, why will SEQUENCE be faster, and will there be a significant performance improvement?

I understand that the SEQUENCE strategy is more efficient because it allows us to use batch inserts and configure the increment value. That's why it seems to me that there is no point in creating a SEQUENCE with an `increment 1` if we don't need to specify a start value or create one sequence for several tables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Instead of asking which is faster, try creating benchmark tests and evaluate the performance differences for yourself. The only major difference between the two options is that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` informs Hibernate that the database will handle sequence generation and `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` informs Hibernate that it is responsible for getting the sequence values. `GenerationType.IDENTITY` probably performs better because the sequence generation will occur when the `INSERT` statement is performed instead of requiring a separate call to the database to fetch the next value.

Comment: An advantage of using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is that it makes the database responsible for handling sequence generation regardless of the platforms used by external applications.